# Why my page refresh when using v-carousel in vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, carousel, vuetify.js

i am using vuetify in vuejs.
in one page i am using two v-carousel the first one is with the cycle prop that can slides your images automatically in every 6s and the second one is simple.
the problem is every time the slides in the first v-carousel component
changes automatically it seems like my page is refreshing.
how to stop that from refreshing my page

```
THIS IS THE FIRST CAROUSEL
<v-carousel
              cycle
              height="400"
              hide-delimiters
              :show-arrows="false"
      >
        <v-carousel-item
                v-for="(slide, i) in slides"
                :key="i"
                reverse-transition="fade-transition"
                transition="fade-transition"
        >
          <v-sheet
                  :color="colors[i]"

          >
            <v-row
                    class="fill-height"
                    align="center"
                    justify="center"
            >
              <div class="display-3">{{ slide }}</div>
            </v-row>
          </v-sheet>

        </v-carousel-item>

      </v-carousel>
```

```
THIS IS THE SECOND CAROUSEL  
    <v-carousel

     >
       <v-carousel-item
               v-for="(item,i) in items"
               :key="i"
               :src="item.src"
               reverse-transition="fade-transition"
               transition="fade-transition"
       ></v-carousel-item>

     </v-carousel>``
```

Comment: I copied and pasted your code and executed it. It works and not refreshing page.

Comment: it actually bring my page to top its like refreshing i am at bottom of the page and after 6s because of the cycle it bring the page to top

Comment: did you find a solution ? @t.khatibi

Answer (score 0):

It worked fine when I removed the height prop.

When you explicitly set the height prop on the v-carousel component, it restricts the height of the carousel to the specified value. This can sometimes cause issues with the scrolling behavior, especially if the content inside the carousel exceeds the specified height.

By removing the height prop, the v-carousel component will adjust its height based on the content inside it, allowing for proper scrolling and preventing the page from jumping to the top.

If you still require a specific height for your carousel, you can try setting the height on the parent container of the v-carousel component instead, ensuring that it has enough space to accommodate the carousel's content.